# Prove that addition under "real numbers" is well defined.

Tags: real-numbers

**Problem:**
If we denote real numbers as Cauchy sequences and:
$$[\{a_i\}]+[\{b_i\}] = [\{a_i+b_i\}] ; i∈ N$$
Show that "$+$" is well defined under real numbers.

**My try:**
Assume that:
$$
\begin{cases}
[\{a_i\}]=[\{a_i'\}]\\ \\
 [\{b_i\}]=[\{b_i'\}]
\end{cases}   (I)$$
We must show that: $$[\{a_i+b_i\}] = [\{a_i'+b_i'\}] $$
From LHS:
$$[\{a_i+b_i\}]=[\{a_i\}+\{b_i\}]$$   $$=[\{a_i\}]+[\{b_i\}]$$  From (I)$$[\{a_i\}]+[\{b_i\}]=[\{a_i'\}]+[\{b_i'\}]$$  $$=[\{a_i'\}+\{b_i'\}]$$ $$=[\{a_i'+b_i'\}]$$

**Is that correct?**

I also checked [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129750/show-that-decimal-addition-on-real-numbers-is-well-defined) but I wanted to try another approach.

Comment: What does the notation mean here, are these equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences? In that case, it looks like your argument is circular. You cannot use $[\{a_i\} + \{b_i\}] = [\{a_i\}] + [\{b_i\}]$ before having proved that that definition even makes sense.

Comment: @sbares Yes. Cauchy sequences.I edited that.

Comment: At one point you wrote the step $[\{a_i\}]+[\{b_i\}]=[\{a_i'\}]+[\{b_i'\}]$, but that's precisely what you're being asked to prove. At some point the definition of the equivalence classes needs to be used.

Comment: @sbares So can you help me how to make my approach correct?

Comment: @GregMartin So can you help me how to make my approach correct?

Comment: You should prove that if $\{a_i\} \sim \{a_i'\}$ and $\{b_i\} \sim \{b_i'\}$ then $\{a_i + b_i\} \sim \{a_i' + b_i'\}$ (here $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that defines the equivalence classes). That will ensure that $[\{a_i + b_i\}]$ does not depend on the representatives of $[\{a_i\}]$ and $[\{b_i\}]$. To do this you need to use the definition of the equivalence relation, and probably do an $\varepsilon$-$N$ proof. The exact details depend on how the equivalence relation is defined.

Comment: No.  You are using in your argument what is required to prove.  I agree with @sbares ... use $\epsilon$-type proof for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments, your proof is not fine as it's using the statement to prove.

Let us denote the sequences by $a=\{a_i\}$ and similarly for $a',\ b,\ b'$.

We have $[x]=[y]$ iff the sequence of the differences of the elements of $x$ and $y$ converges to $0$, i.e. $y_n-x_n\to 0$.

Now, if $[a]=[a']$ and $[b]=[b']$, that means $a_n'-a_n\to 0$ and $b_n'-b_n\to 0$, so using the additive property of limits, we get $c_n:=(a_n'-a_n)\,+\,(b_n'-b_n)\ \to 0$.

But observe that $c_n=(a_n'+b_n')\,-\,(a_n+b_n)=(a'+b')_n\,-\,(a+b)_n$, and this shows $[a+b]=[a'+b']$.

Comment: Thanks.Cleared.